# Labeled grid widget content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blogger

I just want how to make this looking labeled style with javascript.

I tried with every my javascript knowledge, but I think still im short of knowledges.

but it just doesn't appear, and I do not know why

[image]

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
var topstyle = !0,
 relstyle = !1,
 gridstyle = !1,
 gridfullstyle = !1,
 numposts = 1,
    numposts2 = 5,
    no_thumb2 = &quot;https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kPEUmmgnQ68/WAp0aahRFMI/AAAAAAAAAL4/SlE91PhuXYEP8zLp7K6pWd82ASzFoRdVACLcB/w232-h131-c/no_img.png&quot;;
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:content/>?orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=labelthumbs\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>
```

Comment: Photo link is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzYSO.jpg

Comment: Where is the call back function `labelthumbs`? It should be somewhere in your blogger theme.

Comment: I made     <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='content'>adada</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings> this before Javascript, as you can see adada is the posts' label.

Comment: No, you need to add callback function `callback=labelthumbs` to execute json data from your blog.

Comment: Also blogger label is case-sensitive  adada not the same as Adada.